# Jsoup: Getting a link that doesn't show in the HTML

Tags: java, ajax, jsoup

I am working on a little app for myself. I am trying to get a list of links from a site. The site is for example: http://kinox.to/Stream/Prison_Break.html
If you hover over the big window in the middle that says kinox.to best online, it show the link that I want in the bottom left. The problem is if I look at the html file I can't find the link anywhere. I guess it has to do something with the site using JavaScript or Ajax.
Is it possible to somehow get the link using JSoup or are there any other Java libraries that could help me?

Comment: What do you mean where is my code? Everything that I have coded until now is irrelavant for this question. I know how to get html elements using JSoup. The problem is the link that I want is not in the html file of the site. If I hover over the picture/button in the middle it shows me the link that I want in the bottom left. I just have no idea how to get that link because it's not in the html file therefore I can't extract that link using JSoup.

Comment: Well I answered that it is used to extract static parts of html pages.

Comment: If your question is sufficiently answered, you should consider accepting the best answer and thereby mark this question as solved. If you need further help, please specify exactly what you need help with

Answer (score 0):

I did not look closely into the page you try to load, but here is what I think the problem may be: The link is loaded/generated dynamically via JavaScript. Jsoup does not run JavaScript, so therefore you can't find the link in the html.

Two possible solutions:

1) Use something like selenium webdriver to access the content. The Java bindings allow to remote control a real browser which should have no problems loading the page and running all scripts within. Solution 1 is simple to program, but runs slowly. It may depend on an extern browser program which must be installed on the machine. An alternative to webdriver is the JavaFx webkit engine in case you are on java 8.

2) Analyse the traffic and the JavaScript on the page and find out where the link comes from. This may take a bit of time to find out, but when you succeed you can use Jsoup to get all the data you need. This solution should run much faster than solution 1.

Answer (score 0):

One solution and probably the easiest would be to use Selenium:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://kinox.to/Stream/Prison_Break.html");
String mylink = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#AjaxStream > a")).getText();
```